# Making PhP code executes first before Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<?PHP
//$errorMessage = "";
//$check = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
        //===================================================
        //  GET THE QUESTION AND ANSWERS FROM THE FORM
        //===================================================
    $sID = $_POST['studentID'];
    $sID  = htmlspecialchars($sID);
        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $firstName  = htmlspecialchars($firstName);
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
        $lastName  = htmlspecialchars($lastName);
        $grade = $_POST['grade'];
        $grade  = htmlspecialchars($grade);
        //var_dump($grade);

        //============================================
        //  OPEN A CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE
        //============================================
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "surveyTest";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
    if ($db_found) {
        //============================================
        //  GET THE LAST QUESTION NUMBER
        //============================================
            $SQL = "Select * FROM students WHERE SID='$sID'";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $studentID = $db_field['SID'];
            var_dump($studentID);
            //=========================================================
            //  Add a student to the students TABLE
            //=========================================================
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO students (SID, fName, lName, Grade) VALUES ('$sID', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$grade')";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            //=============================================================
           //   SET Multiple rows IN THE answers TABLE for each question for a given student.
           //=============================================================
            /*$SQL = "Select * FROM tblquestions";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); //return number of rows in the table
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $numRows; $i++){
                $qNum = 'q1';
                $SQL = "INSERT INTO answers (QID, A, B, C, D, E, SID) VALUES ('$qNum', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '$sID')";
                $question_Number = ltrim($qNum,'q');
                $question_Number++;
                $qNum ='q'.$question_Number;
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);
            }*/
            mysql_close($db_handle);
            print "The student with the following ID ".$sID. " has been added to the database";
        }
    else {
        print "Database NOT Found ";
        mysql_close($db_handle);
    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Survey Admin Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="setQuestionForm" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="setStudent.php" id="sStudent">
            <p>Enter student ID: <INPUT TYPE = 'TEXT' Name ='studentID' size="4"></p>
            <p>Enter First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="20"></p>
            <p>Enter Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20"></p>
            <p>Select Grade: <select name = "grade">
                <option value = "1">First Grade</option>
                <option value = "2">Second Grade</option>
                <option value = "3">Third Grade</option>
                <option value = "4">Fourth Grade</option>
                <option value = "5">Fifth Grade</option>
                <option value = "6">Sixth Grade</option>
                <option value = "7">Seventh Grade</option>
                <option value = "8">Eighth Grade</option>                           
            </select></p>
            <INPUT TYPE = "submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Add Student">
        </FORM>
    <P>



<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        if ($('form').length > 0) {
            $('form').submit(function(e){
                var check = "<?php echo $studentID; ?>";
                alert(check);
                if (check != "")
                {
                    alert ("This user already exists");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            });   
        } 
    }) 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is used to add students to a database, and I'm trying to do some form validation to avoid duplicated records. My problem is that I set a php  variable $studentID that verifies whether the database contain the a student with the same ID.

However, when I try to add a duplicated record, it seems like my javascript code executes first and this can be observed by the alert message in the JQuery code that it shows a box of an empty string. Executing the code once more, do the correct thing.

Any help of how I can fix this?

Comment: Try running your jQuery code inside `$(window).load()`?

Comment: The problem is that your php code runs after a `POST`.

Comment: @CollinHenderson: `$(function(){ /*...*/ });` is jQuery's way of executing when the document is ready.

Comment: @Travesty3 AFAIK `$(function(){ /*...*/ });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready()`, no? AKA it runs when the DOM is ready, but not necessarily when the page is fully loaded (which `$(window).load()` does)

Comment: Any ideas then?, Any other method of setting precedence?

Comment: @CollinHenderson: Yes, but how would that make any difference in this problem?

Comment: @Travesty3 My initial thoughts were that his jQuery was running before the page finished loading, and was checking non-existent data.

Comment: Its on post so your first iteration will not present any data and you will get a blank alert. One thing you can do is wrap your JS in the <?`<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") : ?> // js code here <?php endif; ?>`. That will only execute JS when the form is posted.

Comment: @CollinHenderson: Please don't take this in a snarky manner, but he is saying that his problem is that the JS executes before his PHP. JS is client-side and PHP is server-side. That has nothing to do with when the listener gets attached to the event. And to my knowledge, the only real difference it would make is if you had to wait for images (for image manipulation) or other frames to load.

Comment: @Travesty3 I'm aware how client/server languages work, I just misinterpreted what he meant. For all I know, his PHP code could have been executing slowly, which would hinder the overall page load, which could cause the JS to run prior to the PHP completing it's execution. I left it as a comment, and not an official answer because I wasn't sure I entirely understood the question, but wanted to offer a possible solution in case I was correct.

Comment: @CollinHenderson: Ok. Now you've piqued my interest. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17533150/259457

Answer (score 5):

On initial page load:
The process flow looks like this:

> Server Side code -> sends data to client -> browser begins rendering and executing JS

On form Submit:

> Client Executes code (javascript) -> Sends data to server -> Server gets data and processes

to change the way this works you would want to do an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) form submit and on "success" then execute the above JavaScript.  You can post to the same page or change it to a RESTful service.

Here are examples of AJAX and POST functions from jQuery:

### AJAX

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

### POST (JS)

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

---

Here is the **result specifically for you**, taking the two snippets above.

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(function () {
    if ($('form').length > 0) {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "YOUR-URL",
                data: YOUR - FORM - DATA,
                success: function (result) {
                    //result will contain the xml or JSON result of calling the FORM
                    var check = "<?php echo $studentID; ?>";
                    alert(check);
                    if (check != "") {
                        alert("This user already exists");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                dataType: "XML-OR-JSON"
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: you are saying that I should use either one of them. Where should I insert this code?

Comment: in your $('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); --INSERT CODE HERE!!! }

Comment: the above code doesn't work. It just allow me to add duplicated records if the rest of the fields are different (It doesn't really add to the database) but, it displays nothing for me.

Comment: The above code is still just pseudo code you will have to make it POST the proper data.  And then the URL to your Webpage or RESTful service

Comment: I still don't understand this code. However, I omitted all the javascript from my file and used php code instead for validation. I never used AJAX before, and that's why I'm struggling to understand this.

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with making the clientside code (ie AJAX) via discussion or chat.  However, you should always be doing Server Side validation, ALWAYS.  Because, you should never trust the client.

Comment: I totally appreciate this. I'll look at AJAX first, and see how can I get it working with your code and then I'll post additional questions.So is it the case that I should use both server side and client side for validation.

Comment: Also, it is saying that my reputation is only 16, not yet enough to chat :). I'm a newbie to stackoverflow :)

Comment: You always want to use both server side validation (can't be easily hacked without access to the server itself) and client side validation (can easily be hacked but can save the user from post backs)